# Style Multiple Links Mermaid JS

Tags: mermaid

Is there any way in Mermaid JS to name the links and avoid having to have a `linkStyle` for every single link in a diagram?

For example, to get the red and black lines in the below diagram, my source looks like the below and the styles are becoming unmanageable.

```
graph TD
    Bat(fa:fa-car-battery Batteries) -->|150a 50mm| ShutOff
    Bat -->|150a 50mm| Shunt

    ShutOff[Shut Off] -->|150a 50mm| BusPos[Bus Bar +]

    Shunt -->|150a 50mm| BusNeg[Bus Bar -]

    BusPos -->|40a| Fuse[Fuse Box]
    BusPos -->|?a| Old{Old Wiring}

    BusNeg -->|40a| Fuse

    Fuse -->|10a| USB(USB-C)
    Fuse -->|10a| USB
    Fuse -->|1.5a| Switch -->|1.5a| Wifi

    Wifi -->|1.5a| Fuse

    Fuse -->|10a| Cig1[Cigarette Lighter]
    Fuse -->|10a| Cig1 

    Fuse -->|10a| Cig2[Cigarette Lighter Near Bed]
    Fuse -->|10a| Cig2 

    BusNeg -->|?a| Old

    Solar --> SolarCont[Solar Controller]
    Solar --> SolarCont

    SolarCont --> BusNeg
    SolarCont --> BusPos

    linkStyle 0 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 1 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 2 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 3 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 4 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 5 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 6 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 7 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 8 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 9 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 10 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 11 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 12 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 13 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 14 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 15 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 16 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 17 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 18 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 19 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
```

[image: Mermaid JS diagram]

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list of ids instead of setting style for each id separately.
For example,

```
graph TD
    Bat(fa:fa-car-battery Batteries) -->|150a 50mm| ShutOff
    Bat -->|150a 50mm| Shunt

    ShutOff[Shut Off] -->|150a 50mm| BusPos[Bus Bar +]

    Shunt -->|150a 50mm| BusNeg[Bus Bar -]

    BusPos -->|40a| Fuse[Fuse Box]
    BusPos -->|?a| Old{Old Wiring}

    BusNeg -->|40a| Fuse

    Fuse -->|10a| USB(USB-C)
    Fuse -->|10a| USB
    Fuse -->|1.5a| Switch -->|1.5a| Wifi

    Wifi -->|1.5a| Fuse

    Fuse -->|10a| Cig1[Cigarette Lighter]
    Fuse -->|10a| Cig1 

    Fuse -->|10a| Cig2[Cigarette Lighter Near Bed]
    Fuse -->|10a| Cig2 

    BusNeg -->|?a| Old

    Solar --> SolarCont[Solar Controller]
    Solar --> SolarCont

    SolarCont --> BusNeg
    SolarCont --> BusPos

    linkStyle 0,1,2,4,5,8,9 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 3,6,7 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 10 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 11 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 12 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 13 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 14 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 15 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 16 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 17 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:red;
    linkStyle 18 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
    linkStyle 19 stroke-width:2px,fill:none,stroke:black;
```

Comment: It's not ideal, but that seems like a slightly better option! (I wonder why it's not documented!)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like style all the links inside a Mermaid.js Diagram with a default style, you can specify `default` instead of a list of ids or an id to `linkStyle`. E.g.:

```
graph TD
A --> B
linkStyle default display:none;
```